# How to support SAML SSO within a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, saml-2.0

I'm trying to add SAML v2 SSO within my google chrome extension as the service provider, but I've been running into a series of problems with this. What are the available options for integrating SAML v2 SSO as the service provider into a chrome extension?

If I try to use an iFrame to direct the user to the identity provider then I am at the whim of the idP to support x-frame-options to allow me to embed it.

When doing some research I found something for communicating with another [SAML SSO for Chrome Apps Extension](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7064180) that could capture cookies for SSO pages to assist with managing SSO sign-ins. But I'm not even sure where to begin with using it. It also seems to require me to use a google admin or google google workplaces account to manage, which is not something our company uses.

Thanks for your help!